# How can I have activity in a Dropbox folder logged?

Tags: monitoring, dropbox

I have a folder shared with others through Dropbox. When a file is added to this folder, I get a system tray notification in KDE --- but of course if I'm not at my computer, I wouldn't see the notification. Is there a way to automatically log any changes within a folder (especially file creation), and/or automatically run a bash script to, say, send an email to myself as a more durable "alert"?

A google search turned up [incron](http://www.howtoforge.com/triggering-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron) ... It sounds about right. Has anyone used this software?

Comment: The inotify API (which is what inotifywait, incron and inoticoming use) is for monitoring changes to *local* files. What you're looking for is a notification of a change on Dropbox's servers. This is [an FAQ on the Dropbox forums](http://forums.dropbox.com/tags.php?tag=notification), and the standard answer is to use RSS (plus an RSS-to-email gateway if you really want email).

Answer (score 6):

You probably want [inoticoming](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html), which is a user space command that uses the inotify framework.  You can use it to watch a directory and execute the script of your choice, which can then do anything you want.

I've used this extensively for monitoring directories for file activity and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty straightforward usecase of inotify, unfortunately that's a programming API, not a user utility.

Comment: `inotifywait` is the basic utility built on the inotify API, and `incron` and `inoticoming` are others. But that's not relevant to monitor a change on a remote server.