# How can I monitor disk I/O in a particular directory?

Tags: linux, monitoring, io, disk-usage

I've got a few processes with a known name that all write to files in a single directory. I'd like to log the number of **disk block reads and writes over a period** (*not* just file access) to test whether a parameter change reduces the amount of I/O significantly. I'm currently using `iostat -d -p`, but that is limited to the whole partition.

Comment: related: [How can I have activity in a folder logged?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3494/863) and [monitoring activity on my computer.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4275/863)

Comment: This is different from those questions, because I'm not interested in the files themselves but rather the amount of I/O.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I realize this is going to sound both simplistic and absurd, but if you have
control over the apps in question (maybe in a test environment) you could 
mount ONLY that directory on a partition of its own, then `iostat`, etc. would
tell you only about it, and nothing else on that spot.

If there are physical drives involved you could fake it up with a loopback
mount à la

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/bigdisk/LOOPFILE bs=1024m count=1024m # 1gb loopback file
mke2fs -j /bigdisk/LOOPFILE
mkdir /tmpcopy
mount -o loop /tmpcopy /bigdisk/LOOPFILE
cp -r -p $SPECIALDIR2MONITOR /tmpcopy
umount /tmpcopy
mount -o loop $SPECIALDIR2MONITOR  /bigdisk/LOOPFILE,
```

That would not completely remove all competing disk I/O, but
I'm pretty sure `iostat`'s output would be more specific to your need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `inotifywait -m DIRNAME` from the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/).

Comment: `-d` doesn't exist in inotifywait 3.13. Do you mean `-m`?

Comment: @l0b0: oh, I use 3.14 from the git repo. sorry. But the manpage states it's the same as `-m` with the exception of running in the background and requiring an outfile.

Comment: also `-r` might be useful

Comment: Tested it. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, but I'm not interested in which files (or even how many files) were accessed, but rather the amount of I/O.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe `inotifywatch` does what you want, but I don't know much about it

Comment: Note, this is Linux-specific. BSDs have kqueue and pnotify system calls, but I don't know if they do exactly what the author is requesting.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a direct way. One way to get the data you want would be to access the directory tree through a [virtual filesystem](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) that logs accesses. [Loggedfs](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/) is one such filesystem, though I don't know if it can show all the data you're interested in. (If not it would probably be a modest coding effort to that data.)

```
mkdir /tmp/replica
loggedfs /path/to/directory /tmp/replica
mycommand --root=/tmp/replica
fusermount -u /tmp/replica
```