# How does the order of arguments influence the speed of find

Tags: find

How does the order of arguments in a `find` call affect the speed of the results?

Compare for example (A)

```
find -name dir -type d
```

and (B)

```
find -type d -name dir
```

Or any other of combinations of arguments (e.g. using `-or` or `-and`). I would expect `find` to be smart in some way.

I tried to collect some statistics by executing both A and B with `time` and 5 repetitions. However with

```
 11.86, 7.23, 5.25, 5.87, 7.16
```

for A and for B:

```
9.73, 6.56, 8.69, 7.14, 6.35
```

this is not really conclusive, with mean values around `7.5s` for both, and quite a high variance.

So, to repeat my question, does the order of arguments matter using `find`?

Comment: There are definitely commands that will reduce the set of files and directories as find goes along parsing commands, but I'm not entirely sure that the order of `-name ..` and `-type d` would matter. Your testing would seem to indicate that it doesn't.

Comment: @slm I am interested in more than this specific example. But I can also not explain the huge differences between the timings...

Comment: I would employ an strace to see what the underlying find is up to to diagnose further.

Comment: @slm see my answer. That does not seem to help.

Comment: I would then move to something like fatrace, https://launchpad.net/fatrace. This will allow you to trace the file events that `find` is triggering which should lead you to a more accurate picture of what files are being "touched" when `find` is running.

Comment: See `fatrace` in action on this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86875/determining-specific-file-responsible-for-high-i-o/87290#87290

Comment: I deleted my answer since Stephane explained that GNU find will reorder its arguments itself so both commands probably do the same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is costly, is doing system calls on the files (for the system calls themselves and for the I/O).

Things like `-type`, `-mtime` require a `lstat(2)` system call on the file. `-name`, `-path`, `-regex` don't (though of course it will have done system calls to the directories they contain to read their content).

Usually, `find` does an `lstat()` anyway (because it needs to know whether a file is a directory or not to descend into it, unless that information is provided in the `readdir()`), but there are cases where it can do without it. For instance, if the number of links of a directory is less then 3, then in some filesystems, `find` knows it doesn't have subdirs, and some `find` implementations will optimise by not doing `lstat`s in there.

`-xtype` will cause a `stat(2)`, `-printf ...`, `-ls` may cause a `stat()`, `lstat()`, `readlink()`, `-lname` a `lstat()` and `readlink()`.

That's why you may want to put the `-name`/`-path`/`-regex`... first. If they can rule out a file, they can avoid one or more syscalls.

Now, a `-regex` may be more expensive than a `-name`, but I'm not too sure you'd get much by swapping them.

Also note that some `find` implementations like GNU `find` do reorder the checks by default when possible. See:

```
info find 'Optimisation Options'
```

on a GNU system ([there on gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Optimisation-Options.html) for the latest version of GNU `findutils`).

Typically, if you did your tests on a GNU system, both commands would do the same thing because `find` would have moved the `-name` forward anyway.

So, for the `-type d -name ...` vs `-name ... -type d` to make a difference, you need a `find` implementation that doesn't optimise by reordering those predicates and one that does some optimisation by not doing an `lstat()` on every file.

Where there will be a (huge) difference regardless of the implementation is in:

```
find . -name 'x*' -exec test -d {} \; -print
```

vs:

```
find . -exec test -d {} \; -name 'x*' -print
```

`find` can't reorder the `-exec` as doing so could introduce functional differences (`find` can't know whether the command that is executed is only for testing or does something else).

And of course `-exec ... {} \;` is several orders of magnitude more expensive than any other predicate since it means forking a process and execute a command in it (itself running many system calls) and wait for it and its exit code.

```
$ time find /usr/lib -exec test -d {} \; -name z\* -print > /dev/null
1.03s user 12.52s system 21% cpu 1:03.43 total
$ time find /usr/lib -name z\* -exec test -d {} \;  -print > /dev/null
0.09s user 0.14s system 62% cpu 0.367 total
```

(the first one calls `test` for every file in `/usr/lib` (56685), the second one only on those files whose name starts with `z` (147)).

Note that `-exec test -d {} \;` is not the same as `-type d`. It's the portable equivalent of the GNU specific `-xtype d`.

Comment: If I understand your first sentence, you're saying that each file/directory that is part of the "found set" needs to be dealt with by having a corresponding system call? The act of making this system call is one of the more costly items, b/c certain calls require, for example, lstat(2) information, right?

Comment: @slm, I'm saying that when `find` has to decide whether a file is selected or not, it's better to put the checks that do not involve a syscall first.

Comment: The `-exec` proof is pretty nice :)