# Execute MySQL commands directly instead of entering console first

Tags: mysql

**PostgreSQL**

In PostgreSQL it is possible to execute commands without entering the `postgres=#` console by executing `sudo -u postgres psql -c "\l"` instead of entering the console first and executing `\l`. By doing this psql commands can be directly executed in one step instead of two steps.

**MySQL**

In MySQL, `sudo -u root mysql -c ""` is not accepted as in PSQL. So the console has to be entered first by executing `sudo mysql -u root` before further commands can be issued.

**Question**

Is it possible to execute MySQL commands directly (one step) instead of entering the console first and issuing commands (two steps) like in PostgreSQL?

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: Please let me know whether the question is still unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the `-e` option, short for `--execte`, right?

From [`man mysql`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mysql.1.html):

```
    --execute=statement, -e statement

        Execute the statement and quit. The default output format is like
        that produced with --batch. See Section 4.2.3.1, “Using Options
        on the Command Line”, for some examples. With this option, mysql
        does not use the history file.
```

Different from PSQL, `-c` is short for `--comments` here:

```
    --comments, -c

        Whether to preserve comments in statements sent to the server.
        The default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable with
        --comments (preserve comments).
```

Comment: @utretch it looks like you want to use the `--help` option and read there too. What if the `-c` option meant `--clear-database`?

Comment: @pqnet For a nice example of this problem, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150628/why-does-find-delete-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-recursively

Comment: i was commenting on that question while you wrote this :-)