# Delete all files by find

Tags: files, find, rm

How to delete all files found by this command?

```
find -type f -name "*-thumb.png"
```

Comment: `man find` --> look for delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find -type f -name "*-thumb.png" -exec rm {} \;
```

If you need a prompt to confirm deletion, use `-ok` in place of `-exec` as:

```
find -type f -name "*-thumb.png" -ok rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

`find -type f -name "*-thumb.png" -delete`

Will work as well. I use it very often after merge resolutions on Git to remove the ".orig" files that Git creates.

Comment: Just be very careful because of this:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150628/why-does-find-delete-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-recursively?rq=1