# Tool to show PID and file I/O in realtime

Tags: files, logs, io

I need to watch a program which modifies some files. I don't know which files the process is modifying_. So I'm looking for a tool that basically outputs a PID, and lista the files being accessed/modified, and what's being done to them (both read and write).

The closest thing I've found so far is [iotop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop), which is definitely on the right track.

```
iotop -o -b -qqq
```

That gets me the process and the read/write, but it *doesn't indicate the file being accessed*. Alternately, I think I could try something like

```
inotifywatch -r /
```

but that just runs out of allowed inotify watches.

What is the magic tool I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already [have your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118601/tool-to-show-pid-and-file-io-in-realtime/118602#118602), but I asked [a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86875/determining-specific-file-responsible-for-high-i-o) before, and we came to the conclusion that `fatrace` is the ideal solution. It should produce much easier-to-read output than a full `strace`.

Documentation is [on the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fatrace.1.html). Basically, you should be able to use the `-p` option to restrict your view to a particular process.

Comment: Amazing. fatrace is literally exactly what I needed, plus it saved me from writing an ugly, janky shell script with strace and grep.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You could go all the way and use `strace` on the program. Yes, it tracks ALL system calls (which includes file io & access and other stuff), so you will get quite a messy printout, but it is immediate and doesn't skip anything (it intercepts calls and reports them). You can do the same with library calls (`ltrace`).

Comment: Yup. It's ugly as hell, but the information I needed was there. Thanks!